# Как сделать так чтобы 2 цикла работали с помощью if else

Tags: c++

Как сделать так чтобы 2 цикла работали с помощью if else

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <cstring>
   #include <Windows.h>

   using namespace std;

 int main()
{
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
char *s;
char str[80];
cin >> str;
s = str;
int i;
char ruseng[32][2] = 
{
    'q', 'й',
    'w', 'ц',
    'e', 'у',
    'r', 'к',
    't', 'е', //
    'y', 'н',
    'u', 'г',
    'i', 'ш',
    'o', 'щ',
    'p', 'з',
    '[', 'х',
    ']', 'ъ',
    'a', 'ф',
    's', 'ы',
    'd', 'в',
    'f', 'а',
    'g', 'п',
    'h', 'р',
    'j', 'о',
    'k', 'л',
    'l', 'д',
    ';', 'ж',
    'z', 'я',
    'x', 'ч',
    'c', 'с',
    'v', 'м',
    'b', 'и',
    'n', 'т',
    'm', 'ь',
    ',', 'б',
    '.', 'ю',
    '`', 'ё'
};

int t;

for(t = 0; t < strlen(str); t++)
{
    for(i = 0; i < 32; i++)
       if(ruseng[i][1] == *s) break;
    cout << ruseng[i][0];
    *s++;
}


  for(t = 0; t < strlen(str); t++)
  {
    for(i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    if(ruseng[i][0] == *s) break;
   cout << ruseng[i][1];
   *s++;
 }


   return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Что значит "работали с помощью if else"?

Comment: если человек вводит слово, то нужно либо в первый цикл либо во второй

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы делал так:

```
const char * eng = "qwerty.... ";
const char * rus = "йцукенг... ";

char* translate(char * s)
{
    for(char* q = s; *q; ++q)
    {
        const char * c = strchr(eng,*q);
        if (c)
        {
            *q = *(rus + (c-eng));
        }
        else if ((c = strchr(rus,*q)) != nullptr)
        {
            *q = *(eng + (c-rus));
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

У вас, как минимум, исправьте - если уж обнаружили символ - то зачем же проверять остальные?

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос у тебя не поставлен от слова совсем, насколько я понял, ты хочешь чтобы вводимая строка определялась как английская или русская, и программа меняла символы на аналоги этих символов другой раскладки на клавиатуре?

Или ты хочешь чтобы просто на просто символ менялся на аналог его другой раскладки на клавиатуре?

Или ты хочешь чтобы только русские символы менялись?

В любом случае, я посмотрел на твой код и "пофиксил" его до такого состояния:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    char str[80];
    cin >> str;
    char ruseng[32][2] =
    {
    'q', 'й',
    'w', 'ц',
    'e', 'у',
    'r', 'к',
    't', 'е', //
    'y', 'н',
    'u', 'г',
    'i', 'ш',
    'o', 'щ',
    'p', 'з',
    '[', 'х',
    ']', 'ъ',
    'a', 'ф',
    's', 'ы',
    'd', 'в',
    'f', 'а',
    'g', 'п',
    'h', 'р',
    'j', 'о',
    'k', 'л',
    'l', 'д',
    ';', 'ж',
    'z', 'я',
    'x', 'ч',
    'c', 'с',
    'v', 'м',
    'b', 'и',
    'n', 'т',
    'm', 'ь',
    ',', 'б',
    '.', 'ю',
    '`', 'ё'
    };

    for (int t = 0; t < strlen(str); t++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        {
            if (str[t] == ruseng[i][0])
                cout << ruseng[i][1];
            else if(str[t] == ruseng[i][1])
                cout << ruseng[i][0];
        }
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну, если уж обнаружили символ - то зачем же проверять остальные?

Comment: @Harry Я не предлагал своих решений, а исправил его

Comment: Спасибо.........